# Can I prevent other callers from intercepting SignalR Hub messages on the same hub?

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

The SignalR server hub does not retain a list of groups so I assume that when I send out a broadcast message to a group it is sent to everyone connected to the hub and the clients filter out the message based on their participating groups. If I send a message to a specific group it seems that it is sent down the wire to everyone and can be intercepted by someone  not in the specified group who knows how to use a browser debugger. If I want to have a secure broadcast (not even sent over the wire to some clients) I assume I need separate hubs or do I need separate sub domains?

Answer (score 0):

Separate hubs do not sound like a good idea. While you probably can validate users on connect and refuse connections for non-authorized users what if you need a way to create isolated hubs dynamically. If however this functionality is enough for you you can use the [Authorize attribute](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) to secure either hubs or hub methods.

For cases where you do need to replicate the same functionality for different groups of users you can use SignalR groups but you need to verify that the user belongs to the group each time he connects. The SignalR documentation contains an example on how to do that [verification](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#verify). Note that everyone can try to connect to your groups and you should validate upon connection and not depend on the fact that you do not call the add method for a certain client.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can see I didn't explain myself well so I edited my questions. I don't think that validating a persons membership in a group actually prevents the data from being sent over the wire. It appears to be insecure if I want to broadcast to just one group. The Authorize attribute on a method seems to only work for preventing clients from calling a method and does not affect a broadcast. Using authorize on the hub means I'm back to multiple hubs with the same functionality.

Comment: I always assumed that messages to groups are only sent to clients who joined that group. Do you observe otherwise?

Comment: I have't tested it but [the documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub) says " the server does not maintain lists of groups or group memberships.  This helps maximize scalability, because whenever you add a node to a web farm, any state that SignalR maintains has to be propagated to the new node. " 

if it doesn't have a list then it's fair to assume it can't enforce security so it is probably done on the client.

Comment: Yes, you can't get the list of users in the group but you can deny access to a group. However you must do this explicitly. You can't just not add the user to the group. You have to validate the connection to the group. As far as I understand this is analogous to login in a web server. The server does not maintain a list of logged in users it just validates every request.

Comment: I don't see how to "validate the connection to the group". In this case the client is not making a request. It is receiving a broadcast from the server. I don't see any documentation where it shows that the message sent to a group is filtered by the server. The documentation implies the server can not filter it because it does not retain a list of groups or users. I can think of several ways they could do it but I don't see where they say they are. Since it's security you assume it is not secure until you have documentation that it is.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR only sends to the clients in the group. It's just a design issue that you can't retrieve a list of connections in a group. Groups, as pretty much everything else in SignalR, are subscription based, so the server knows which connections need to receive a message, but it's buried deep in the internals.

I would point you to the relevant server-side code, but don't have time to look it up right now.
It's easy to see in the client-side code though since it's not a lot of code - so you can verify there is no filtering going on there.

Groups also aren't separated per hub.

Comment: Can you provide a link to something that substantiates what you claim?

Comment: uh..just download a sample project, connect 2 clients and try it, that's the fastest way to confirm; otherwise.. this: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Comment: alright, took a quick look and here's a hint: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Hubs/HubConnectionContext.cs (see comment for OthersInGroup)

Comment: That does not make claims about their underlying security. I plan on running the test but it will take a while. Was hoping someone already checked it.

Comment: it says "A dynamic representation of all clients in a group", so the server knows which clients are in a group and so obviously doesn't need to broadcast to all clients if you're sending to the group; so it does validate what I said; I don't know what you mean with "security" in that context; anyway, if that doesn't convince you, you're on you own, sorry